# DLL issue in Xamarin.Forms Android in Visual Studio

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

```
Error
   Exception while loading assemblies: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load assembly 'Microsoft.Windows.Design.Extensibility, Version=4.3.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'. Perhaps it doesn't exist in the Mono for Android profile?
File name: 'Microsoft.Windows.Design.Extensibility.dll'
   at Java.Interop.Tools.Cecil.DirectoryAssemblyResolver.Resolve(AssemblyNameReference reference, ReaderParameters parameters)
   at Xamarin.Android.Tasks.ResolveAssemblies.AddAssemblyReferences(DirectoryAssemblyResolver resolver, ICollection`1 assemblies, AssemblyDefinition assembly, Boolean topLevel)
   at Xamarin.Android.Tasks.ResolveAssemblies.Execute(DirectoryAssemblyResolver resolver)   MyApps.Radiocity.Droid  C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.Common.targets   1413
```

I am facing the above issue in Android(Xamarin.forms). Since four days i am trying to find out the solution for this.

**Please any one can tell the solution for the above issue?**

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft.Windows.Design.Extensibility is not a DLL that is compatible with Android. You shouldn't need it in there. Go to your References and remove this DLL.

If you have this DLL in any of your Class Libraries attached to this project, remove it from there as well.